# React + Redux - Call a method of a component wrapped for the Redux Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, tdd, provider

Whats'up,

I am trying to test some react components that uses redux.

The default behavior should load by a rest call a list of options in a select input. This call is on the method componentDidMount() in my component.

The component works fine, but I cannot simulate the same behavior in my tests.

I cannot call the method componentDidMount() from my instance wrapped by Provider.

Can anyone help me with this

```
import React from 'react'
import {expect} from 'chai'
import {mount, shallow} from 'enzyme'
import sinon from 'sinon'

import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import ConnectedComponent from '../../../src/components/Component'

describe('Component <Component />', () => {
    let store = createStore(combineReducers({ form: formReducer }))
    let wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><ConnectedComponent /></Provider>)

    // this call does not works
    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()

    it('should load select input on component mount', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('select option')).to.have.length(12)
    })
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't `mount` do that for you? Why call a lifecycle method directly?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do like the following :

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

export class Mock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    myMethod() {
        return 123
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Test</div>
        )
    }
}

Mock = connect()(Mock);

export default Mock;
```

Jest test snippet :

```
const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Mock/>
    </Provider>
)
let result = wrapper.find(Mock).children().instance().myMethod();
expect(result).toEqual(123);
```

hope that helps someone!